# find the Equivalence classes of this equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Is this correct?

Let R and S be the equivalence relations on Z X Z defined by

((a,b),(c,d)) ∈ R if and only if ab=cd

and 
((a,b),(c,d)) ∈ S if and only if ad=bc

Find the equivalence class $[(3,4)]_R$

$[(3,4)]_R$= {cd=12,c and d in Z}

Comment: That is the correct equivalence class for $[(3,4)]_R$, although you should write it as $\{(c, d) : cd = 12, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ to show that the elements of the equivalence class are ordered pairs of integers. However, note that $S$ is not actually an equivalence relation, because $(0,0)$ is related to every $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. You can thus use $(0,0)$ to come up with a counterexample to the transitive property that equivalence relations must satisfy.

Comment: Okay, noted. Thanks!